# Why am I getting unexpected EOF while parsing in my eval() function

Tags: python, tkinter, eval

I am trying to make a "moderately scientific" calculator GUI using python's tkinter module.
I am fairly new to using classes and methods
I have run the code after "typing" in different expressions into the entry box but every time it comes up with the error unexpected EOF while parsing.
The traceback shows builtin code so I have not made a syntax mistake in my actual code.

```
#Import modules used
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as m #am importing this seperately as the IDE I use does not like it for some reason
import math

#Create class for the buttons that will be used
class Button():
  def __init__(self,i,j,texttext,evaluatory=True):
    global main_frame
    self.output=tk.Button(master=main_frame,relief=tk.RIDGE,text=texttext,
    bg=self.get_colour(texttext),command=lambda : process(texttext,evaluatory),
    font=("Arial",10))
    if texttext == "=":
      self.output.configure(fg="white")
      colspan=2
      xpad=5
      ypad=5
    else:
      if texttext == "AC":
        self.output.configure(fg="white",font=(None,10,"bold"))
      colspan=1
      xpad=3
      ypad=3
    main_frame.rowconfigure(i,weight=1)
    main_frame.columnconfigure(j,weight=1)
    self.output.grid(row=i,column=j,columnspan=colspan,sticky="N"+"E"+"S"+"W",padx=xpad,pady=ypad)

  def get_colour(self,texttext):
    nums=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    if texttext.replace(" ","") in nums:
      colour="#FFA500"
    elif texttext == "=":
      colour="#000000"
    elif texttext == "AC":
      colour="#FF0000"
    else:
      colour="#F270EB"
    return colour

#replaces expressions used in calculator display with expressions to be used in eval() 
def checkthrough(string):
  string=string.replace("e","math.e")
  string=string.replace("Exp(","math.exp(")
  string=string.replace("π","math.pi")
  string=string.replace("√(","math.sqrt(")
  string=string.replace("sin(","sine(")
  string=string.replace("cos(","cosine(")
  string=string.replace("tan(","tangent(")
  string=string.replace("arcsin(","arcsine(")
  string=string.replace("arccos(","arccosine(")
  string=string.replace("arctan(","arctangent(")
  string=string.replace("fac(","factorial(")
  string=string.replace("ln(","math.log(")
  string=string.replace("Ans","ANS")
  string=string.replace("^","**")
  string=string.replace("log(","math.log10(")
  return string

#To allow use of Rad and Deg buttons properly, these functions help use trig functions
def sine(number):
  global mode
  if mode == "Deg":
    return math.sin(math.radians(number))
  else:
    return math.sin(number)

def cosine(number):
  global mode
  if mode == "Deg":
    return math.cos(math.radians(number))
  else:
    return math.cos(number)

def tangent(number):
  global mode
  if mode == "Deg":
    return math.tan(math.radians(number))
  else:
    return math.tan(number)

def arcsine(number):
  global mode
  if mode == "Deg":
    return math.degrees(math.asin(number))
  else:
    return math.degrees(math.asin(number))

def arccosine(number):
  global mode
  if mode == "Deg":
    return math.degrees(math.acos(number))
  else:
    return math.acos(number)

def arctangent(number):
  global mode
  if mode == "Deg":
    return math.degrees(math.atan(number))
  else:
    return math.atan(number)

#Factorial function - forgot math.factorial existed but hey-ho
def factorial(n):
  answer=1
  while n > 1:
    answer*=n
    n-=1
  return answer

#Handles event of button presses
def process(button_value,evaluatory):
  global expression
  global started
  global entry
  global mode
  global ANS
  if not started:
    started=True
    entry.delete(0,tk.END)
  modes=["Rad","Deg"]
  if button_value in modes:
    mode=button_value
  if button_value == "=":
    expression=entry.get()
    expression=checkthrough(expression)
    if expression.count("(") != expression.count(")"): #Means brackets must be closed before eval() called
      m.showinfo("Syntax","Remember to check your\n bracket count and\nmake sure they are\nall complete!")
    else:
      ANS=eval(expression)
      entry.delete(0,tk.END)
      entry.insert(0,ANS)
      started=False
  else:
    if evaluatory:
      entry.insert(tk.END,button_value.replace(" ",""))
    else:
  if button_value != "AC":
    entry.insert(tk.END,insert_values[button_value])
  else:
    entry.delete(0,tk.END)

def main():
  #give variables global scope and define most
  global ANS
  global main_frame
  global expression
  global started
  global mode
  global entry
  global insert_values
  insert_values={"exp":"Exp(","pi":"π","1/X":"1/(","X^3":"^3","sqrt":"√(","sin":"sin(","cos":"cos(","tan":"tan(","log":"log(","arcsin":"arcsin(","arccos":"arccos(","arctan":"arctan(","ln":"ln(","n!":"fac(","X^2":"^2"}
  started=False
  expression=""
  ANS=0
  mode="Deg"
  window=tk.Tk()
  window.resizable(0,0)
  window.geometry("500x300")
  window.configure(bg="#00008B")
  window.title("Moderately Scientific Calculator")
  entry=tk.Entry(master=window,font=(None,22),justify=tk.RIGHT)
  entry.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
  entry.insert(0,"0")
  main_frame=tk.Frame(master=window,bg="#431C53")
  main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
  #Create all the buttons that will be used
  grid=[["(",")","exp","pi",",","AC","1/X","/"],
  ["Rad","Deg","X^2","sqrt"," 7 ","8","9","*"],
  ["sin","cos","tan","log"," 4 ","5","6","-"],
  ["arcsin","arccos","arctan","ln"," 1 ","2","3","+"],
  ["n!","X^3","e","Ans",".","0","="]]
  non_evals=["exp","pi","AC","1/X","Rad","Deg","X^2","sqrt","sin","cos","tan","log","arcsin","arccos","arctan","ln","n!","X^3"]
  for x in range(5):
    for y in range(8):
      if x != 4 or y != 7:
        if grid[x][y] in non_evals:
          Button(x,y,grid[x][y],False)
        else:
          Button(x,y,grid[x][y])
  #Bind event of return key pressed to function, set focus and 'start' window
  window.bind("<Return>",lambda event:process("=",True))#No I don't know why I need the parameter
  entry.focus_set()
  window.mainloop

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

"""This is also my first time using Stack Overflow so I may not have added my code correctly"""
I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks

Comment: You need to cut down on the amount of code. I'm willing to bet you don't even need half of that code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the expression that you've computed, before passing it to `eval`, or are you just assuming it's correct?

Comment: Please, include stacktrace and error message

Comment: @Shaken_not_Stirred As Bryan Oakley indicated, it would be of considerable help to us if you could pare down the posted code to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can focus on the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Yeah, that is a huge amount of code. First step is add `print(repr(expression))` and see if its something obvious. Next, see if you can reduce the problem to a canned input. Looking at your code, you really depend on the user clicking buttons in exactly the right order. Evaluation errors will be common with this code.

Comment: Having copied and tested the code, the reason for the error is simple: you never actually set `expression` equal to the input string.

Comment: Most probably that this line `expression.replace("√","math.sqrt(")` will have missing closing `)` in the expression. For example `"√64"` will be replaced by `"math.sqrt(64"`.

Comment: first you should display expression  before you run `eval` and check if it has all closing `)`

Comment: String replacement is really not a good practice here -- tools built that way are inevitably fragile. Learning to build a proper parser that builds an AST, and then an evaluator that runs that AST, will put you in good stead. Any textbook on compiler design will cover good practices, or you can just start with a library built for the purpose; there's a huge number to choose from at https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing

Comment: ...given the above list of available libraries, a formal CS education will give you the tools needed to decide which grammar type is appropriate, or you can just opt for something that's modern and widely flexible like PEG. :)